# JsonSerializer.Deserialize performance in Blazor WebAssembly vs Blazor Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a blazor webassembly app that makes calls to a database with ~5000 rows and that requires a few joins (using EF .Include()). The entire JSON object is downloaded by the client in 800ms.  My problem is that the JSON deserialization process takes too long once the JSON reaches the client app. The bottleneck appears to occur at `Http.GetFromJsonAsync<T>` which of course implements `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>`. After fetching the data (800ms), it takes blazor another 6-8 seconds to deserialize my JSON before displaying it to me.

More information on this issue can be found here:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40386

I have already tried a few of the suggestions such as running it in release mode and using Firefox. The benefits were present but minimal, not enough to solve my issue. So, in light of this I have 2 questions:

1)Would switching this app to a Blazor Server app improve my deserialization performance?

2)Are there other steps I can take to improve client side deserialization in a blazor wasm app?

```
<Virtualize Items="fooList" Context="foo">
   <FooSummary @key="foo" Foo="@foo"></FooSummary>
</Virtualize>


@code {
    private List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        fooList = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Foo>>("Foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-5.0 ?

Comment: @BrianParker yes, I have updated my question to show my implementation

Comment: I would [EnableQuery] on the api and use OData paging which should pass through to the db if set up properly.

Comment: As for the first question - server and client apps are two entirely different things, cannot be compared. So it will of course improve serialization performance when you switch, but you will have completely different application then. As for second question - seems the only reasonable way right now is to not download and use so much data at once, and use paging or virtualization. That issue you linked also claims that moving to .NET 5 can make it twice faster

Comment: Thank you for raising this question. I hope there will soon be a solution. However, for your specific case, one might suggest having a serverside API in-between that handles paging of your data so only the visible data is loaded into the users browser.